# Overlapping pixels with convert -crop

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Suppose i have a long chat screen which i want to split into the chunks. But i want overlapping between chunks for editing them after with Gimp.

I use right now like this:

**convert chat.png -crop 100%x25% +repage chat_%d.png**

How to create overlapping with pixels or percentages between them like 50px for example? That first screen have 50px of top of next screen and etc.

I have tried to find the solution, but cannot to find.

*I need linux version syntax. Pls. Below is windows cmd one. How to convert it?*

Comment: If this is a screen capture and you make clean cut you don't need any overlap to reconstruct the image in Gimp. But why do you cut them first. Why not edit directly in Gimp (Gimp can also cut in chunks later if necessary)?

Comment: There is no option in Imagemagick -crop to overlap.  You have to write a script loop using -crop to overlap.  I have a script called overlapcrop that does that at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want a Linux solution, I wrote a little **bash** script. You can edit the number of chunks and the number of lines to overlap near the top of the script. You can also edit the code to pass the filename, number of chunks and overlap in as parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

# User editable values
image="image.jpg"   # filename of image
overlap=50          # vertical overlap in pixels
chunks=6            # number of output images

# Get image height and work out basic lines per chunk excluding overlap
h=$(identify -format %h image.jpg)
lpc=$((h/chunks))
echo "DEBUG: height=$h, Lines per chunk=$lpc"

for ((chunk=0;chunk<$chunks;chunk++)) ; do
   (( top=chunk*lpc ))
   (( lines=lpc + 2 * overlap ))
   # First and last chunks only have 1 overlapped edge
   [ $chunk == 0 ] || [ $chunk == $((chunks-1)) ] && (( lines=lpc + overlap ))
   
   echo "DEBUG: chunk=$chunk, top=$top, height=${lines}"
   magick "$image" -crop x${lines}+0+${top} "chunk-${chunk}.jpg"
done
```

I am using this image:

[image]

Photo by [Dave](https://unsplash.com/@iamthedave?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/swH_IVJGLDA?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText)

I get these results:

```
DEBUG: height=2688, Lines per chunk=448
DEBUG: chunk=0, top=0, height=498
DEBUG: chunk=1, top=448, height=548
DEBUG: chunk=2, top=896, height=548
DEBUG: chunk=3, top=1344, height=548
DEBUG: chunk=4, top=1792, height=548
DEBUG: chunk=5, top=2240, height=498
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create the effect of a crop with overlapping segments using ImageMagick with a command like this in Windows CMD syntax...

```
magick lena.png +duplicate -background none ^
   -roll "+0-%[fx:t*50]" -crop 100x25% -splice 0x50 -roll "+0-%[fx:t<(n/2)?50:0]" ^
   null: -insert %[fx:n/2] -layers composite lenacrop-%02d.png
```

That reads in the image, then by duplicating it, and cropping and rolling as needed it creates two cropped sets, one with the 50 pixel vertical offset.

Compositing the first set over the ones with that extra 50 pixels extended from the bottom results in four output images, cropped evenly, and extended by the 50 pixels below its position in the original image.

The 50 pixel offset is specified three places in the command. Change them to whatever amount of overlap you want.

Running that command on the common sample image "lena.png", The results are these four images...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last output image has the 50 pixels rolled from the very top of the original image added to the bottom edge.

For a BAT script, double the percent signs "%%".

Comment: Any idea how to convert this into linux version?

Comment: You should be able to just replace all the `^` line-continuation characters at the end of each line with a backslash `\\`.